# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException error when starting Android Studio + weird iOS behavior

Tags: java, android, ios, macos

I was setting up my environment for React Native according to: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

After I was done with the steps I restarted my computer and things started to get bad, on reboot:

- My dock was reset to only factory apps
- Wallpaper changed to default
- Files on my Desktop were completely messed up
- All password for programs and websites were reset
- Programs and Websites behaved like I would open them for the first time
- I get frequent errors 'Permission denied' many operations
- When I start Android studio (which worked fine before) I receive this error message:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Users/nico/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/port.lock
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lockPortFiles(SocketLock.java:239)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lockAndTryActivate(SocketLock.java:159)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemDirs(StartupUtil.java:553)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:213)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64 by JetBrains s.r.o
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

I deleted and reinstalled Android Studio with no success, when I restart my computer I get the same behavior every time.

Can someone please explain me what is going on?

Comment: Are you running low on space on your drives?

Comment: 24gb are available

Comment: Well, there goes my guess.